# Dates appearing in list as datetime.date(YYYY,M,D)

Tags: python, list, datetime

I have a script that is printing the dates at a certain interval between a start date and an end date that is specified by the user. The dates are being printed in the format YYYY-MM-DD as in 2023-06-08. This is the format I like.

In addition to printing the dates, I added some code that is appending these dates to a list. However, when I run this code, the same dates are being entered into the list as [datetime.date(2023,6,1)]. Is there a way around this?

```py
sections = []


#year month day format
barstartdate = datetime.date(int(startyear),int(startmonth),int(startday))
#year month day format
barenddate = datetime.date(int(endyear),int(endmonth),int(endday))
#delta time
delta = datetime.timedelta(days=7)
#iterate over range of dates
while (barstartdate <= barenddate):
    print(barstartdate, end="\n")
    sections.append(barstartdate)
    barstartdate += delta

print(sections)
```

Output:

```
2023-06-01
2023-06-08
[datetime.date(2023, 6, 1), datetime.date(2023, 6, 8)]
```

For reference, the start date and stop date in this case was `2023-06-01` and `2023-06-14`. The last bit of code shown is the output I am getting in my console. The first two dates are appearing as I want them to, but the list has an odd format. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `print` an object it will convert the object to a string using the `str()` built-in. However, when you print a list, the objects inside the list will be converted using `repr()`.

For many classes `str()` and `repr()` will return the same string, but not for `date` objects:

```py
>>> str(datetime.date.today())
'2023-06-15'

>>> repr(datetime.date.today())
'datetime.date(2023, 6, 15)'
```

What you are seeing in the list is the string [representation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) of a `datetime.date` instance. You need to convert them to strings using [`.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) or, in your case, using the shortcut method [`.isoformat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoformat).

Try replacing

```
sections.append(barstartdate)
```

with

```
sections.append(barstartdate.isoformat())
```

Additi

Comment: When you `print` an object it will convert the object to a string using the `str()` built-in. However, when you print a list, the objects inside the list will be converted using `repr()`. For many classes `str()` and `repr()` will return the same string, but not for `date` objects. It is better to explicitly convert objects to strings instead of counting on Python's default behaviour.

Comment: makes sense, thank you for the explanation and answer! The code you provided works perfectly!